# Validate username and password without postback in login form ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, validation, postback

I want to validate the entered username and password entered in the textboxes present in a form without Postback/Refresh. I know I am gonna need Javascript or AJAX for this purpose, but somebody please guide me through this like refer me to any tutorial or please explain me the code here. 
My present code without this feature looks like this:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.PPNumber, new { @class = "form-control", type = "number", placeholder = "Enter Number",@min="1" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.PPNumber)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Password, new { @class = "form-control", type = "Password", placeholder = "Password" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Password)
    <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" />
}
```

Comment: [Remote validation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(v=vs.98).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) is one way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ajax.

When user submits the form, you need to hijack that event in javascript and stop that(*prevent the normal full page form submit*) and instead make an ajax call to the action method with the form data. This action method should have code to verify the user credentials and can return a JSON data structure which has a `status` property which says whether the credential validation is successful or not. You can inspect this response in your ajax call's success/`done` callback and act accordingly.

Here is a quick sample using jQuery `$.post` method.

Give an Id to your form so that we can use that to wire up the submit event.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id="loginForm"))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.PPNumber)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Password, new { @class = "form-control", type = "Password"})
    <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" />
}
```

and the javascript code to hijack the submit event and do an ajax post instead.

```
$(function () {

    $("#loginForm").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize())
            .done(function(response) {
                if (response.status === 'success') {
                    alert("Login successful.Do something else now");
                } else {
                    alert("Login failed");
                }
            });
    });
});
```

Assuming your Login action method in AccountController will return a Json response with a status property.

```
public ActionResult Login(string PPNumber,string password)
{
    if(PPNumber=="thisIsDemo" && password=="ButDoTheActualCheck")
    {
        return Json(new { status = "success" });
    }
    return Json(new { status = "failed" });
}
```

Here i just hard coded the usrename /password check to 2 static values. You can change that to check it against your db table/whatever your credentials checking mechanism is.

Comment: Thanks a lot Shyju, It helped me very much.